# Items added to ControlCollection not showing

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to add some Checkboxes to a panel with this code:

```
    For t = 0 To taglist.Count - 1  'list(of string)
        'new ComboBox
        Dim cbx As New CheckBox

        'some options
        cbx.ThreeState = True
        cbx.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
        cbx.Name = "cbxTag" & cnt
        cnt += 1
        cbx.Text = taglist.Item(t)
        'cbx.Top = (y + 2) * 10
        'cbx.Left = x * 30 + 10
        cbx.Location = New Point(x * 60 + 5, (y) * 20 + 20)

        'Add it to controls
        SplitContainer2.Panel1.Controls.Add(cbx)

        ' Positioning stuff
        If x * 60 + 65 < SplitContainer2.Panel1.Width Then
            x += 1
        Else
            x = 0
            y += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Using debug i see that the items got added to the collection and the position seems right (in a visible position).

The problem: Only the first item of each row appears on the form. 
Edit: The problem seems to be something with the x koordinate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When adding items to a SplitContainer.Panel the items will format accordingly. It's possible the top & left logic is wrong. Can you comment that part of the code out and see if your items just get added? Also are you sure you have more than 1 item in your list?

Comment: okay, they got added after commenting the top & left part. found `.location` - trying this to get the items in position. any other ways?

Comment: Add a FlowLayoutPanel to the splitpContainer.Panel you are adding the check boxes to. then add the checkboxes to the FlowLayoutPanel.Contros. The FlowLayoutPanel will take care of positioning the checkboxes for you.

Comment: thanks! i didnt know about them. i still have to learn a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the size of the checkbox. Unlike to a checkbox added in the designer the `Autosize` property is FALSE when creating a checkbox with `Dim cbx As New CheckBox`.

The result was that they got created with a size around 80 - 100 and appeared to be overlaping each other in a way they were not visible ( the background of the first checkbox hid the checkbox of the second and so on.)

so the solution to my problem was :

```
 cbx.AutoSize = True
```